# Xcode - can't build app for production with aps-environment set to production

Tags: xcode

I am getting this message when setting "aps-environment" to "production" in my entitlements.plist file:

**The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.**

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016).

My entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>123.*</string>
    </array>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>123.com.app.mine</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a valid distribution certificate for the app ID -- and it can't be a wildcard one

Answer (score -1):

First go to developer.apple.com login in member centre select manage profile, certificate section.
1) create Certificate of type distribution (if you want it to upload to App Store)

2) create app id you should enter same package name as specified in your application

3) create provisional profile with the same certificate and app identifier which you had 
already created.

4) download certificate and profile

5) go to build setting of your application target and select the particular profile and certificate which you had downloaded.

Hope it will resolve your issue

Comment: :: (if you want it to upload to App Store) > no -- he always needs a diet cert as he wants to use the ape-environment for dist!